# How to route to same location to restart view and controller binding (angularjs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually, I want something like this `location.path(location.url());` but angular by default doesn't allow this. Is there a way to override it?

I need this to renew view and controller binding?

Why?

So, I have in my model statements like this:

```
$scope.instance = 
{
    City: gettextCatalog.getString(cityName),
    Country: gettextCatalog.getString(countryName),
}
```

So, if I change a language, the `$scope.instance` will not be recalculated. I think, that rebinding on reroute is more easy way than inserting every 'instance' in function, that will be called after language changed.

Comment: You want to reload current route again?

Comment: @User2, Yes it is.

Comment: Try $route.reload()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **ngRoute**

```
$route.reload()
```

> $route is used for deep-linking URLs to controllers and views (HTML
>   partials). It watches $location.url() and tries to map the path to an
>   existing route definition.
>
> **reload()**;
>   Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location
>   hasn't changed.
>   As a result of that, ngView creates new scope and reinstantiates the
>   controller.

If you are using **ui.router**

```
$state.go($state.$current, null, { reload: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$route.reload();
```

From the angular docs:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>   As a result of that, ngView creates new scope and reinstantiates the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using $scope.$apply() ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. First, it causes error "rootScope.inprog". Second it is not comfortable solution anyway, because I have several controls on the page that include both view and controller and I need refresh all of them at the same time. This means that if choose `$apply()` way, I should do it to every control on the page manually. IMHO, rerouting is simplier.